# Django - Taking of object model by select tag and passing this object to another view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm struggling with the following problem. In my project I have the following model:

**models.py**

```
class InputSignal(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    adnotations = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    input_file = models.FileField(upload_to='signals/', null=False, validators=[validate_file_extension])
    add_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    last_json_results = models.FileField(upload_to='resuts/')

    objects = models.Manager()

    def delete(self):
        self.input_file.delete()
        super().delete()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def add_date_pretty(self):
        return self.add_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

Two url addresses:

**urls.py**

```
path('display/list', displayviews.display_list, name='display-list'),
path('display/details/<int:signal_id>', displayviews.display_details, name='display-details'),
```

And two view functions:

**views.py**

```
def display_list(request):

    signals = InputSignal.objects.filter(author=request.user)

    return render(request, 'display_list.html', {'signals': signals})

def display_details(request, signal_id):

    signal = get_object_or_404(InputSignal, pk=signal_id)
```

The template of the first function of the view at this moment looks like this:

**display_list.html**

```
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    <select class="form-control mt-2 text-center">

        {% for signal in signals %}
            <option>
            <h2>{{ signal.name }}</h2>
            </option>
        {% endfor %}

  </select>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1"></div>
</div>

<div class="row mt-3 mb-2">
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <a href="{% url 'storage-main' %}" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">Perform Analysis</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
</div>
```

I would like based on the structure of this template to design a solution that after selecting the signal name from the select tag and clicking the 'perform analysis' button, go to the next view - display_details (request, signal_id). Where I will save the previously selected model object to the variable. Choosing the right object I would like to use the object ID. I would like to ask for help, what I was able to design presented above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things here.

To submit data from a web page you need a form element (unless you're using Ajax, which doesn't seem necessary here). Your select box needs a `name` attribute, and each option needs a value to submit. Also, you can't submit a form with an `a` link; you need a submit button. So:

```
<form action="{% url 'display-details' %}">
    <select name="signal_id" class="form-control mt-2 text-center">

        {% for signal in signals %}
            <option value="{{ signal.id }}">
            <h2>{{ signal.name }}</h2>
            </option>
        {% endfor %}

    <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block">Perform Analysis</button>

</form>
```

Now this data is being submitted in the querystring to your display_details view, eg "/display/details/?signal_id=5". So you need to remove the parameter from the URL pattern, and get the data inside the view from the GET params:

```
path('display/details/', displayviews.display_details, name='display-details'),
```

...

```
def display_details(request):
    signal_id = request.GET['signal_id']
    signal = get_object_or_404(InputSignal, pk=signal_id)
```

Comment: Using your solution, a signal_id appears in the URL, which a clever user can use to access other InputSignal models. I found out that the easiest way to do this is to replace the GET method with the POST method, but I do not know how to approach it.

Comment: I assumed that's what you wanted, because it was originally in your URL as a path parameter. Using POST instead doesn't really help security, you can still easily get round it. Instead you should filter by author in the display_details view like you do in the index: `signal = get_object_or_404(InputSignal, pk=signal_id, author=request.user)` or explicitly check `signal.author == request.user` and raise HttpResponseForbidden if not.

Comment: I apologize if I have expressed myself imprecisely, I am a novice developer.